# ConcurrentHashMap Implementation

Tags: java, thread-safety, hash-map, concurrency, synchronization

I have written a simplified version of my own `MyConcurrentHashMap`. I tried to make use of a `Lock[]` array for `Lock` striping, so that all `put()` operations to the `MyConcurrentHashMap` is through a lock if required. Also, I made my own `MyHashMap` made internally as the backing data structure for `MyConcurrentHashMap`. I created it my own as I wanted to qualify the value field as volatile for volatile read operation without an explicit locking. This ensures that the `get()` operation is a non synchronized call with implicit locking at memory level though volatile read and not via acquiring a lock anytime which makes it lighter. Have a look and provide your inputs and improvements if any:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class MyConcurrentHashmap {

    private static final int DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 16;

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    private float LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;

    private int capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

    private int size;

    private Lock[] locks;

    private MyHashMap myHashMap = new MyHashMap();

    private class MyHashMap {
        private LinkedList[] lists = new LinkedList[INITIAL_CAPACITY];

        private class MapEntry {
            final Object key;
            volatile Object value;

            MapEntry(Object key, Object value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        void put(Object key, Object value) {
            if (key == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key Cannot be Null");
            int hash = key.hashCode();
            hash %= lists.length;
            if (size >= LOAD_FACTOR * lists.length) {
                capacity = lists.length * 2;
                LinkedList[] tempLists = new LinkedList[capacity];
                System.arraycopy(lists, 0, tempLists, 0, lists.length);
                lists = tempLists;
                reHash();
            }
            if (lists[hash] == null) {
                lists[hash] = new LinkedList<>();
                size++;
            }
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < lists[hash].size(); i++) {
                MapEntry mapEntry = (MapEntry) (lists[hash].get(i));
                if (mapEntry != null && mapEntry.key.equals(key)) {
                    mapEntry.value = value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == lists[hash].size()) {
                lists[hash].addLast(new MapEntry(key, value));
            }
        }

        Object get(Object key) {
            int hash = key.hashCode();
            hash %= lists.length;
            Object value = null;
            if (lists[hash] != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lists[hash].size(); i++) {
                    MapEntry mapEntry = (MapEntry) (lists[hash].get(i));
                    if (mapEntry != null && mapEntry.key.equals(key)) {
                        value = mapEntry.value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

        private void reHash() {
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                if (lists[i] != null) {
                    int hash = ((MapEntry) lists[i].getFirst()).key.hashCode();
                    hash %= lists.length;
                    if (i != hash) {
                        lists[hash] = lists[i];
                        lists[i] = null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        int size() {
            return size;
        }

        int capacity() {
            return capacity;
        }
    }

    public MyConcurrentHashmap(int concurrencyLevel) {
        locks = new Lock[concurrencyLevel];
        for (int i = 0; i < concurrencyLevel; i++) {
            locks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
        }
    }

    public MyConcurrentHashmap() {
        this(DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL);
    }

    public void put(Object key, Object value) {
        int hash = key.hashCode();
        hash %= myHashMap.capacity();
        locks[hash].lock();
        myHashMap.put(key, value);
        locks[hash].unlock();
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        return myHashMap.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyConcurrentHashmap myCCHashMap = new MyConcurrentHashmap();
        myCCHashMap.put(1, "Thomas");
        myCCHashMap.put(9, "Mathew");
        myCCHashMap.put(17, "Tissa");
        myCCHashMap.put(9, "Mathew Thomas");
        System.out.println(myCCHashMap.get(1));
        System.out.println(myCCHashMap.get(9));
        System.out.println(myCCHashMap.get(17));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty complicated task and I'd bet there'll be problems.

With `volatile Object value` you assure visibility of `value`, but `Object key` gets read before it and it's not `final`. So there are good chances, it'll break.

---

```
    if (capacity == LOAD_FACTOR * lists.length) {
```

With floating-point multiplication, this may never happen. With your `LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f`, it may as `0.75` can be represented exactly, but e.g., with `0.4` it'll fail. The test should be `<=` or `>=`, no idea which one is right.

Possibly none, as you're testing `capacity`, which never changes. It should be `size >= LOAD_FACTOR * lists.length`.

---

The correctness of your `get` depends on the internal working of the `LinkedList`.

---

```
    for (; i < lists[hash].size(); i++) {
        if (((MapEntry) (lists[hash].get(i))) != null
                && ((MapEntry) (lists[hash].get(i))).key.equals(key)) {
            ((MapEntry) (lists[hash].get(i))).value = value;
            break;
        }
```

As `LinkedList` has an inefficient `get`, this is doubly inefficient. Actually triply as you're using it twice. You should iterate the list instead.

Do you put any `null`s in the list? If no, then you don't need to test for them.

Use a local variable for `lists[hash]` and also for the `i`-th element.

Don't `break` when you can `return` and save yourself the test in

```
    if (i == lists[hash].size()) {
        lists[hash].addLast(new MapEntry(key, value));
    }
```

---

```
    hash %= lists.length;
```

As your list.length is always a power of two, you can this much faster hack:

```
    hash &= lists.length - 1;
```

---

```
  public Object get(Object key) {
    Integer hash = key.hashCode();
    hash %= myHashMap.capacity();
    return myHashMap.get(key);
  }
```

Why `Integer`? Why `hash` at all when you don't use it?